# TypeScript: module name "../TypeFiles/Address" has not been loaded yet for context

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015, requirejs

I am learning typescript (using VS2015) and stuck at export/import modules.
I am getting an error "**module name "../TypeFiles/Address" has not been loaded yet for context**".

I created two classes Customer & Address and tried to import address in customer class.

```
 import {Address} from "../TypeFiles/Address";
 class Customer {

 public adderessObj: Address = new Address();

 private _CustomerName: string = "";
 public set CustomerName(value: string) {
    if (value.length == 0) {
        throw "Customer name is required.";
    }
    this._CustomerName = value;

 }
 public get CustomerName(): string {
     return this._CustomerName;
 }
}

export class Address {
   public Street: string = "";
   public City: string = "";
   public Pincode: string = "";
}
```

I downloaded requirejs (RequireJS 2.3.2) and added it in my html page.

```
<script src="Scripts/require.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TypeFiles/Customer.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your `tsconfig.json` or what parameters do you pass to `tsc`? Also, did you copy the error message correctly? That error message is common but I've never ever seen it with an empty string as a module name. That's baffling.

Comment: don't have any tsconfig.json. I am using VS2015.
This is the complete error "Uncaught Error: Module name "../TypeFiles/Address" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])"

Comment: The problem is the same as the problem in the question against which I've closed your question. The solution is the same. If you do not know how to get VS2015 to pass a configuration to `tsc`, then ask a specific question about how to get VS2015 to pass a configuration to `tsc`. (But check first that no one asked it before.) At any rate, the meat of the problem is explained in my answer to that other question.

Comment: I should mention if the module output format is not explicitly set, then it is `commonjs` unless your target is `ES6` (in which case the module format is `ES6` too). At any rate, the error you got can *only* be produced when trying to have RequireJS process CommonJS `require` calls.

Comment: If you want to ask a question about how VS2015 does this or that, ask *another question*. The question you asked here has been disposed of.

Comment: I don't know about the tsconfig.json thing, I created a project in vs2015 and start using typescript.

Comment: Yes, you can ask *another question* that focuses *on that problem*, if you need to. But make sure that it has not been asked yet. When I look with appropriate keywords, I [see *a lot of questions*](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvisual-studio-2015%5D+%5Btypescript%5D+tsconfig.json) that pertain to `tsconfig.json` and VS2015.